# apply-templates in the right order if the XML tags are not ordered

Tags: html, xml, xslt, transformation

I'm trying to convert a XLST transformation, i got the following XML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="xlstransfo.xsl"?>

<breakfast_menu>

<food>
<name>Belgian Waffles</name>
<price>$5.95</price>
<description>
two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple syrup
</description>
<calories>650</calories>
</food>

<food>
<name>Strawberry Belgian Waffles</name>
<description>
light Belgian waffles covered with strawberries and whipped cream
</description>
<price>$7.95</price>
<calories>900</calories>
</food>

<food>
<name>Berry-Berry Belgian Waffles</name>
<price>$8.95</price>
<description>
light Belgian waffles covered with an assortment of fresh berries and whipped cream
</description>
</food>

</breakfast_menu>
```

My problem in this XML is that the children node of  are not necessarily in the same order.

I try to do an XLS to transform it in HTML :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
    <body>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="/breakfast_menu/food"/>
    </body>
</html>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/breakfast/food">
<xsl:apply-templates select="name"/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="price"/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="description"/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="calories"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/breakfast_menu/food/name">
    <div style="background-color:3366FF; font-weight:bold; color:FFFFFF;display:inline">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/breakfast_menu/food/price">
    <div style="color:white;background-color:3366FF;display:inline">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/></div>
        <br />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/breakfast_menu/food/description">
    <div style="background-color:C0C0C0;display:inline">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/breakfast_menu/food/calories">
    <div style="background-color:C0C0C0;font-style:italic;display:inline">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/> calories per serving</div>
    <br />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The elements always come out in the order of the tags in the XML. Which means i got a correct Name-Price-Description-Calorie order for the first item, and then a wrong Name-Description-Price-Calorie for the second item.

How can i fix that from the XLST (without modifying the XML file) ?

I'm using Altova XMLSpy for the transformation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with this line...

```
<xsl:template match="/breakfast/food">
```

`breakfast` is not an element in your XML, so this template will not match anything. Instead the [built-in templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule) will apply, which will select the children of `food` in document order.

You should change it to this...

```
<xsl:template match="/breakfast_menu/food">
```

In fact, the full path is unnecessary in this case. You could also replace it with this:

```
<xsl:template match="food">
```

The same goes for the other templates. For example `<xsl:template match="/breakfast_menu/food/price">` could be replaced with `<xsl:template match="price">`. You would only really need to full path if you have elements with the same name in different parts of the hierarchy for which for wanted different templates to apply, for example.

Comment: Oh thank you. Indeed, it works. Thanks for the intel, i thought i need the whole thing, and didn't pay attention to the name mistake. Altova is producing a not-well formed html (End tag name 'body' does not match start tag name 'br') but i don't know if it's my fault or the transformation processor's.

Comment: Actually the problem disappeared for like no reason (just tried another transformation...) EDIT : actually it appear or not randomly at each transformation.